# Mixin method to dispatch Toast's does not work when not in main loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toast, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-toast

I am using VueJS and a Vue mixin method like this so as to have this toast method available in my components:

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    makeSuccessToast(message, toaster) {
      this.$bvToast.toast(message, {
        title: 'Success',
        variant: 'success',
        toaster: toaster || 'b-toaster-bottom-right',
        solid: true,
        autoHideDelay: 2000,
        noHoverPause: true,
        appendToast: true,
      });
    },
  },
});
```

It does not work when calling this method via setTimeout or setIntervall or when debouncing it with lodash. It simply won't work when trying to make toasts via bootstrap vue's toast helper out of the main loop process whatever. Anyone know a fix for it?

Example when it won't work inside a VueJS component:

via `setTimeout` in a component `method`:

```
    doSomething() {
      setTimeout(() => {this.makeSuccessToast('Something happened')}, 2000);
    }
```

via lodash's debounce:

```
  data(){
    this.dsth: ()=>{};
  },
  methods:{
    doSomething() {
      this.makeSuccessToast('Something happened');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   this.dsth = this._.debounce(this.doSomething, 5000);
  }
```

**Edit**:

I didn't realize I was doing a Toast in a component that gets removed. The Toast should have been a notification that this component is deleted. Toasts will vanish as soon as the component is removed so that's why I thought it doesn't work. The solution was to dispatch toasts on the root element in the Mixin method via:

`this.$root.$bvToast.toast(...)`

Comment: Can you provide a way to reproduce the problem? I don't see anything that could prevent it from work this way and not another. Are you certain it works without setTimeout?

Comment: yes it works without setTimeout. What do you need to reproduce it?

Comment: Stackblitz, Codesandbox, etc would be great to debug it.

Comment: What do you use? Webpack vue.js, Vue CLI, just a CDN link? we need more explanation.

Comment: hey thanks for the interest in this. I just realized that I call this in a component which gets removed when the toast is dispatched so the toast wont appear. I am sorry my bad for not realizing this earlier

Comment: oh man, thank you for this question, i had the same problem :D so solution is use this: this.$root.$bvToast.toast instead of this: this.$bvToast.toast 
thanks!